# .NET Webhandler Test string equality comparison fails

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing

I am currently writing tests for my .NET application. To test a webhandler, I am calling it with a webclient and am planning to compare it with a string coming from a file, which I previously have written.

I am storing the expected string in a file, because the WebHandler is generating a html-document, which I am returning as text/plain.

This is the code I am using currently:

```
private string getWebResponse(string projectName)
{
    string url = "http://webhandler.ashx?parameter={0}";
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    return client.DownloadString(string.Format(url, projectName));
}

[TestMethod()]
public void ProcessRequestTest1()
{
    string expected = File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine(projectRootFolder, "testresults", "Test (1).txt"), Encoding.UTF8);
    Assert.AreEqual(expected, getWebResponse("Test (1)"));
}
```

When running this testcase, the test fails even though the strings returned appear to be identical (as I have tested both of them with a diff-tool). Is there an issue that I am missing when gathering the strings?

Comment: Maybe your diff tool is broken. Use `String.Equals(expected,getWebResponse("Test (1)"),StringComparison.Ordinal)`

Comment: What is an ordinal comparison  @TimSchmelter ? Moreover it still fails for me. Tried it manually again by copypasting the result of the method and the expected string into githubs gist, telling me that there are no differences. What came to my mind were linebreaks, is it possible that `File.ReadAllText()` and the webclient parse them differently?

Comment: It is better to use DownloadData to get byte array and File.ReadAllBytes to get byte array also, then compare it. There is something difference there.

Comment: @marv: maybe it's better to use  `Assert.IsTrue(expected == getWebResponse("Test (1))`

Comment: Correct @x... there is a difference, but none that affects my results as I would like them. I guess it is a problem with the parsing, but I ran out of ideas what it might be

Comment: Still telling me that the strings are different @TimSchmelter , but now 100ms faster (at least :( )

Comment: It's impossible to help further. It seems that both are really different. That might be an invisible character or other issue that your diff-tool ignores. Without seeing the real strings we can't help to fix because it could be anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue were the newline characters. My webhandler defined newlines as `\n`. Copy-Pasting the result from my handler into a file lead me to a different string as windows is using `\r\n` for linebreaks.